# How to add icon below CircularAvatar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: Look at the plus]

How can achieve that plus icon as same as the image above.
I tried but am not able.

My code till now i am stucked here! have no idea how to add plus there!

```
 Widget _circleCard(image, name) {
    double radius = 32;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: radius + 4,
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: radius + 2,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: radius,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/$image'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(name)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

plss help beginner me!
Thanks

Comment: Use stack widget

Comment: use `Stack` instead of `Column` and below `CircleAvatar(...)` wrap your icon in `Align()` with `alignment: Alignment.bottomRight` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Stack widget:

```
 Widget _circleCard(image, name) {
    double radius = 32;
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: radius + 4,
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: radius + 2,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: radius,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/$image'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 0.0,
            bottom: 0.0,
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
            ],
          ),
          Text(name)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```